# New-Object cannot contain a dash (-) but "needs to"

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv

I am creating a new object for export values to CSV:

```
New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
            host_name = ($server.name).ToLower()
            address = $IPAddress
            host_is_collector = "no"
            host-preset = "windows-server"
        } | Select-Object host_name,address,host-preset | Export-Csv -Path $nConf_import_host_file
```

The problem is that one of the lines contains a dash (host-preset). I would ofcourse simply change it to an underscore, but my CSV needs this value to be a dash. I could also do a -replace on the entire csv after it has been created but that seems dirty.
Is there a way I can use dash here?

My error msg is:

```
Missing '=' operator after key in hash literal.
At Z:\Scripts\Testscripts\ScanServers_and_check_nagiosV7.ps1:336 char:16
+                 host-preset <<<<  = "windows-server"
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingEqualsInHashLiteral
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You simply need to treat the `host-preset` property name as a string by **enclosing it in quotes**:

```
New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{ "host-preset" = "windows-server" }
```